# Sample from each group in polars dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'm looking for a function along the lines of

```py
df.groupby('column').agg(sample(10))
```

so that I can take ten or so randomly-selected elements from each group.

This is specifically so I can read in a LazyFrame and work with a small sample of each group as opposed to the entire dataframe.

### Update:

One approximate solution is:

```py
df = lf.groupby('column').agg(
        pl.all().sample(.001)
    )
df = df.explode(df.columns[1:])
```

### Update 2

That approximate solution is just the same as sampling the whole dataframe and doing a groupby after. No good.

Comment: Why not just `df.groupby('column').sample(10)`?

Comment: @BeRT2me `AttributeError: 'LazyGroupBy' object has no attribute 'sample'`

Comment: Similarly, `AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'sample'`

Comment: Why the pandas tag?

Comment: @creanion someone who didn't know better must have edited it to add it. It was tagged as python-polars only, originally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let start with some dummy data:

```py
n = 100
seed = 0
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "groups": (pl.int_range(0, n, eager=True) % 5).shuffle(seed=seed),
        "values": pl.int_range(0, n, eager=True).shuffle(seed=seed)
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (100, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ groups ┆ values │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 55     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ 40     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 57     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 99     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 87     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 96     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 43     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 44     │
└────────┴────────┘
```

This gives us 100 / 5, is 5 groups of 20 elements. Let's verify that:

```py
df.groupby("groups").agg(pl.count())
```

```
shape: (5, 2)
┌────────┬───────┐
│ groups ┆ count │
│ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ i64    ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪═══════╡
│ 1      ┆ 20    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 20    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 20    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 20    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ 20    │
└────────┴───────┘
```

### Sample our data

Now we are going to use a window function to take a sample of our data.

```py
df.filter(
    pl.int_range(0, pl.count()).shuffle().over("groups") < 10
)
```

```
shape: (50, 2)
┌────────┬────────┐
│ groups ┆ values │
│ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ i64    ┆ i64    │
╞════════╪════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 85     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ 0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 84     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 19     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...    ┆ ...    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 87     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 96     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3      ┆ 43     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 4      ┆ 44     │
└────────┴────────┘
```

For every group in `over("group")` the `pl.int_range(0, pl.count())` expression creates an index row. We then `shuffle` that range so that we take a sample and not a slice. Then we only want to take the index values that are lower than 10. This creates a `boolean mask` that we can pass to the `filter` method.

Comment: Souldn't you shuffle before you assign the int_range? Or is the execution order here not from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

We can try making our own groupby-like functionality and sampling from the filtered subsets.

```
samples = []
cats = df.get_column('column').unique().to_list()
for cat in cats:
    samples.append(df.filter(pl.col('column') == cat).sample(10))
samples = pl.concat(samples)
```

---

Found `partition_by` in the documentation, this should be more efficient, since at least the groups are made with the api and in single pass of the dataframe. Sampling each group is still linear unfortunately.

```
pl.concat([x.sample(10) for x in df.partition_by(groups="column")])
```

---

Third attempt, sampling indices:

```
import numpy as np
import random

indices = df.groupby("group").agg(pl.col("value").agg_groups()).get_column("value").to_list()
sampled = np.array([random.sample(x, 10) for x in indices]).flatten()
df[sampled]
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. Will give it a try.

Comment: The issue is, you have to go through the dataframe each time every time you filter. If you have hundreds or thousands of categories, you pay a huge price for this.

Comment: It seems like you can use `df.groupby("group").agg(pl.col("value").agg_groups())` to get indexes from each group all in one operation. Then it remains to sample from those and gather all the groups (and it of course returns too many indexes).

Comment: Updated my answer with what I think should be a slightly more efficient method using [partition_by](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html#polars-dataframe-partition-by)

Comment: @creanion that's right, but it just kicks the can down to sampling from one of the lists now.

Comment: Sampling a list of indexes and then only gathering the rows selected for the sample should be a step up in performance

Comment: @creanion I agree, let's see if I can work a solution.

Comment: I made an attempt at it as well~