# Sampling from lists in polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"group" : ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
                   "elements" : [
                                 pl.arange(0, 100, eager=True), 
                                 pl.arange(200, 300, eager=True), 
                                 pl.arange(300, 400, eager=True)
                                ],
                   "weight": [0.1, 0.5, 0.4]})

print(df)
┌───────┬───────────────────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ elements          ┆ weight │
│ ---   ┆ ---               ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ list[i64]         ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════╪════════╡
│ foo   ┆ [0, 1, … 99]      ┆ 0.1    │
│ bar   ┆ [200, 201, … 299] ┆ 0.5    │
│ baz   ┆ [300, 301, … 399] ┆ 0.4    │
└───────┴───────────────────┴────────┘
```

How would I sample e.g. 5 elements from each of the lists in the `elements` column, such that my dataframe looks something like this?

```
┌───────┬───────────────────────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ elements              ┆ weight │
│ ---   ┆ ---                   ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ list[i64]             ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════════╪════════╡
│ foo   ┆ [7,42,19,74,33]       ┆ 0.1    │
│ bar   ┆ [209,277,222,291,260] ┆ 0.5    │
│ baz   ┆ [300,347,312,398,369] ┆ 0.4    │
└───────┴───────────────────────┴────────┘
```

If I then wanted to sample a total of 1000 `elements` from across all `groups`, weighted according to the `weight` column, how would I go about doing that?

I've seen this question: [Sample from each group in polars dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72633461/sample-from-each-group-in-polars-dataframe) which I think is probably similar, but so far I haven't been able to come up with the combination of expressions that will work.

Comment: For [1] you can [`.eval`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.arr.eval.html#polars.Expr.arr.eval) e.g. `df.with_columns(pl.col("elements").arr.eval(pl.element().sample(5)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when polars does a sample or shuffle by group it doesn't randomize each group, it just broadcasts the randomization from one to the other groups. (At least as of v0.17.6) I think this is a feature as I imagine most datasets are such that the elements go to together although I'm not sure.

If you do a `partition_by` and a `concat` you can force it.  Another complication is the dynamic sizing that you're looking for since `sample` only takes an `int`.

Your example `df` doesn't have 1000 elements to choose but if you wanted a total of 100 it might look like this:

```
n=100
(
    pl.concat([
        dd.lazy().with_columns(
            pl.col('elements').arr.explode().shuffle().implode()) 
        for dd in df.partition_by('group')
    ])
    .with_columns(
         elements=pl.col('elements').arr.take(pl.arange(0, pl.col('weight')*n))
    ).collect()
)
```

If you look at the inner most part of this, you see that it's exploding/shuffling/imploding the elements. That operation is wrapped in a list comprehension whose source is a partition of the original `df` by group. Because of that, it forces the shuffle to be independent for each group. The last line is taking the, now shuffled, list of elements and `take`s the first `weight * n` elements. I don't know if making each of the inner frames lazy actually will help in practice but it adds the potential for parallelism.

Another way to do it is to use numpy for randomness and then filter.

```
dfe=df.explode('elements')
(
    dfe
        .with_columns(
            rand=pl.lit(np.random.uniform(0,1,dfe.height))
            )
        .sort(['group','rand'])
        .with_columns(j=pl.col('rand').cumcount().over('group')) #cumcount has to be off of a column, choose one arbitrarily
        .filter(pl.col('j')<n*pl.col('weight'))
        .groupby('group')
        .agg(
            pl.col('elements'), 
            pl.col('weight').first()
            )
)
```

In this way we explode the `df` saving it to a new variable since we need the new height to make the random column. We then sort by the random variable, create a new `j` column that represents the in-group index. We then just filter such that the in-group index is less than the threshold and then `groupby`.`agg` to get back to the original shape.

Comment: I don't think taking the first `weight * n` elements of each group is the equivalent of a random sample with those weights.

Comment: If it's sorted in random order, which it is, then it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is easiest to `explode` the arrays so it's all in one working column, then you can do "regular" expressions on them like `sample`, then `implode` the result back to list:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('elements').arr.explode().sample(5, seed=0).implode().over('group'))
```

(`seed` given for certain output in this example):

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────────────────┬────────┐
│ group ┆ elements          ┆ weight │
│ ---   ┆ ---               ┆ ---    │
│ str   ┆ list[i64]         ┆ f64    │
╞═══════╪═══════════════════╪════════╡
│ foo   ┆ [29, 1, … 10]     ┆ 0.1    │
│ bar   ┆ [229, 201, … 210] ┆ 0.5    │
│ baz   ┆ [329, 301, … 310] ┆ 0.4    │
└───────┴───────────────────┴────────┘
```

As far as part 2... with the exploded column, without an `over` you can get an overall sample like so:

```py
pl.col('elements').arr.explode().sample(1000)
```

But with no `weights` in the `sample` method, I don't think this can be done with pure Polars. You could feed an `exploded` DataFrame into `random.choices`:

```py
dfe = df.explode('elements')
random.choices(dfe.get_column('elements'), weights=dfe.get_column('weight'), k=1000)
```

Comment: It looks like polars isn't randomizing each group but just doing one randomization and broadcasting that to the subsequent groups. See how each row of `elements` starts as 29, 229, 329 respectively.

Comment: Well that's frustrating! Although I can see the logic of why that happens.